# frequency and percentage counts across multiple columns

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have data that looks like:

```
print(dat)
i1  i2  i3  i4
 0   1   1   0
NA   1   1   1
 0   0   0   1
 1   1   1   1
```

My goal is get three pieces of information ideally through some combination of a function and `sapply`: the number of ones, the number of 0s, and the percentage of non-NAs that are 1s.  So for example the ideal result here would be something like:

```
function(dat)
0  1   percentage
5  10      66.7
```

Thanks!

Comment: `table(as.matrix(dat))` should get you started

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here one option:

```
c(sum(mat==0,na.rm=TRUE),
  sum(mat==1,na.rm=TRUE),
  round(sum(mat==1,na.rm=TRUE)/sum(!is.na(mat))*100,1))

## 5.0 10.0 66.7
```